# Entity Framework Core UseTpcMappingStrategy() - How to make each table have its own identity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm writing a code-first database project and I'm using `UseTpcMappingStrategy()` to create table from inherited classes.
I wanted to have several tables with own identity not shared between all of children of base class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("GAME");

    var armorPrototype = modelBuilder.Entity<ArmorPrototype>();
    armorPrototype.HasBaseType<ItemPrototype>();
    armorPrototype.ToTable("ArmorPrototypes");

    var itemPrototype = modelBuilder.Entity<ItemPrototype>()
        .UseTpcMappingStrategy();

    var weaponPrototype = modelBuilder.Entity<WeaponPrototype>();
    weaponPrototype.HasBaseType<ItemPrototype>();
    weaponPrototype.ToTable("WeaponPrototypes");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Migration from this code generated:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
            name: "ItemPrototypeSequence",
            schema: "GAME");

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ArmorPrototypes",
            schema: "GAME",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(20,0)", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "NEXT VALUE FOR [GAME].[ItemPrototypeSequence]"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                Value = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(20,0)", nullable: false),
                IsUsable = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                IsEquippable = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                IsTradable = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                IsUpgradable = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                UpgradeLevel = table.Column<byte>(type: "tinyint", nullable: false),
                RequiredLevel = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                Rarity = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                DefenseValue = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                EquippableBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ArmorPrototypes", x => x.Id);
            });
```

My question is how to skip DbSequence and give each table own id generation. Wondering if making two-column key will be enough to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

They should not have individual Identities because the point of having inheritance whether TPH or TPC is so that all items can be treated as items and EF/code needs to be able to uniquely identify them in all cases reliably.

For example you could load Armor and Weapons to be stored in a set of type ItemPrototype. If the sub-classes had individual sequences for their IDs you would have the potential to have duplicate IDs in the collection. The whole point of inheritance is that any/all subclasses can be treated as their base class, and this includes being able to uniquely identify them when put alongside other subclasses. The alternative of an ID and discriminator is how it would structure a TPH data structure in a single table. The downside of TPH is the fact you end up with a lot of null-able fields since only some fields apply to each inherited type so they must still be null-able for the rows that are for a different type even though you might prefer to treat them as required for their specified type.

Another option would be to use composition rather than inheritance where you could have an ItemPrototype table/entity with an optional associated WeaponPrototype and/or ArmourPrototype. The ItemPrototype would control the ItemPrototypeId as an identity with a 1-to-0/1 relationship with the Weapon and Armour prototype tables which share that same ItemPrototypeId PK + FK back to the ItemPrototype.

The advantage of a composition model over an inheritance one is that it can be more flexible. For instance if you want to have an item that can act as *both* a weapon and an armor, this is possible with composition and impossible with inheritance without defining a new ArmorWeaponPrototype type. The ItemPrototype can reveal whether it can be treated as a weapon or armor based on the existence of an associated WeaponPrototype or ArmorPrototype respectively.